# How can I associate a global register variable to %gs (or %fs)?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64

On x86_64 I'm playing with a toy OS that won't support multithreading.

I tried to associate two [global register variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Register-Variables.html#Global-Register-Variables) to %gs and %fs,  this way:

```
register Foo* foo asm("gs");
register Bar* bar asm("fs");
```

but GCC complains that "gs" and "fs" are not valid register names.

I tried with other registers (eg r12 and r15) and it compiled.
I tried with %gs and %fs and the compilation errors persists.

Is it possible to use these registers this way?
Moreover [I've read about issues with these registers](https://github.com/swetland/xv6/blob/master/README.CLS) in amd64, but I'm unable to understand the problem pointed there: is it a GCC bug or a problem with the use of register variables in amd64?

Comment: Those are selectors (16 bit and special bitfields), so you can't expect to use them as pointers, or anything, really.

Comment: @Jester, I'm pretty new to assembly, can you elaborate? At https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture I read that they are pointer to extra data...

Comment: upvoted because even though the OP's specific question (storing pointers in segment regs) is not sensible, the question of how to use segment registers from C is interesting.  Although I think FUZxxl's answer that just using regular global variables will probably be as fast, if not faster, is a good one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An 80386 compatible CPU has six *segment registers* named cs, ds, ss, es, fs, and gs. These segment registers are used for a feature called *segmentation* and basically act as a pointer into a *segment descriptor table,* whose pointees are implicitly added in address computations.<sup>†</sup>

These segment register cannot be realistically used to hold arbitrary data as all but certain specific ways (`les` and friends) to load a value into them results in an exception when you load an invalid value. They are used for the following purpose:

- The segment register cs is used when fetching instructions, ds when fetching data, ss when fetching data from the stack (i.e. relative to esp or ebp) and es is used in conjunction with certain instructions like scasb. In almost every instruction with a memory operand, you can override what segment the address is resolved against.
- Changing cs is used to change between real mode, 16 bit protected mode, 32 bit protected mode and long mode by the operating system. On Windows, this can also be done by an application (but is not recommended). Changing cs is done by doing a far jump or call.
- OpenBSD implements an execution-prevention scheme (W^X) by setting a length limit on cs, so that no data is both writable and executable at the same time.
- The fs and gs segments are never used by default and are commonly employed to implement [*thread-local storage*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage). You can set the offset associated with fs and gs using the `arch_prctl` system call on Linux, but keep in mind that doing so breaks the expectations by the libc as to what offset is stored in the segment descriptor table for these segment descriptors and may make basic facilities such as `errno` unusable.
- In long mode (64 bit mode),  the whole segmentation mechanism is not available. fs and gs can be used but their value is not looked up in the segment descriptor table, instead there are two special register in which the kernel deposits an offset that is added whenever fs and gs are used. All other mechanisms are unavailable.

---

<sup>†</sup> This is a simplified description, it's actually a bit more complex.

Comment: Thanks FUZxxl, but actually this is the operating system's code, so that libc, errno and tls are not real issues. Since I do not need thread-local storage in this OS, I want to use them for another thing. The questions are: is it possible? if so how? if not, why?

Comment: Also, note that I only care about x86_64

Comment: @GiacomoTesio What do you want to use them for?

Comment: How is this relevant for the question? One to globally provide info about the current process and the other to globally provide info about the cpu running it.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio Your use cases (if one address space can comprise multiple processes/threads) are exactly what thread local storage is usually used for. Read [this article](http://wiki.osdev.org/TLS) for how to set up fs and gs in long mode. The other segment registers aren't usable in long mode.

Comment: No, sorry I probably explained the use case badly: this is not tls since the info I want to point from the registers are not available to the user space processes, they are for the **kernel** consumption.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio What do you think you gain from using segment registers for this purpose? I don't see any advantage. Why not use a simple global variable? The overhead is likely comparable to the use of segment registers, especially considering that liberal use of segmentation isn't exactly an optimized case in modern 80386 compatibles.

Comment: this would require a rather long explaination... I have to dedicate (at least) one register to these variables. I might use only one register but this would complicate the C code. Thus I'd prefer to use 2 registers since I do not care much about the performances here. The point of the question, is not if this design is appropriate given the requirements. What I need to know is how to use these two **unused** registers instead of, say, %r15 and %r14. And if it's not possible, why. This kernel already supports paging, however.

Comment: As I said above: Writing a value into these registers with no corresponding entry in the segment descriptor table causes an exception. See the segment registers (including fs and gs) as a part of the MMU configuration. You cannot just use them for an arbitrary purpose and they would hold only 2 bytes of data each anyway. You can however set up fs or gs for TLS usage and then use the memory region their descriptors point to for variables. This is called thread local storage and is very easy to use.